# How to login to BaseX using Python?

Tags: python, xml, database, nosql, basex

How do I login to `BaseX` as below:

```
nicholas : 
nicholas : basex
BaseX 9.0.1 [Standalone]
Try 'help' to get more information.
> 
> show users
Username  Permission  
--------------------
admin     admin       
nicholas  none        

2 user(s).
> 
> password
Password: 
Password of user 'admin' changed.
> 
> xquery user:list-details()[@name = 'admin'] 
<user name="admin" permission="admin">
  <password algorithm="digest">
    <hash>hjklhjkhj</hash>
  </password>
  <password algorithm="salted-sha256">
    <salt>jkljlkjkljl</salt>
    <hash>jljkljkljl</hash>
  </password>
</user>
Query executed in 235.21 ms.
> 
> exit
Have fun.
nicholas : 
nicholas : python3 basex.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basex.py", line 4, in <module>
    session = BaseXClient.Session('localhost', 1984, 'admin', 'jljljkl')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/BaseXClient/BaseXClient.py", line 116, in __init__
    self.__swrapper.connect((host, port))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/BaseXClient/BaseXClient.py", line 92, in <lambda>
    return lambda *arg, **kw: getattr(self.__s, name)(*arg, **kw)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
nicholas :
```

using [sample](https://pypi.org/project/BaseXClient/) Python as:

```
from BaseXClient import BaseXClient
from parsel import Selector

session = BaseXClient.Session('localhost', 1984, 'admin', 'jkljkljlk')

print(session.info())

   # create new database

session.create("database", "<x>Hello World!</x>")

print(session.info())



    # run query on database

print("\n" + session.execute("xquery doc('database')"))

    # drop database
 #   session.execute("drop db database")

print(session.info())

#finally:
    # close session

if session:
    session.close()
```

I can only reset the password so many times.

Perhaps this won't work from `standalone` mode?

https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Database_Server

says:

Server

> The database server handles concurrent read and write transactions,
>   manages user permissions and logs user interactions. It can be started
>   as follows:
>
> ```
> Run one of the basexserver or basexserver.bat scripts. Add the stop keyword to gracefully shut down the server.
> If you have installed BaseX on Windows, click on the BaseX HTTP Server (Start) icon, which will start both the HTTP Server used for
> ```
>
> Web Applications and the database server. With BaseX HTTP Server
>   (Stop), you can shut down the server process.
>
> By default, the server listens to the port 1984. Pressing Ctrl+c will
>   close all connections and databases and gracefully shut down the
>   server process.
>
> Various command-line options are available to simplify batch
>   processing. The start script can be adjusted for individual purposes
>   (e.g. if the default memory limit is too restrictive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have basexserver running in order to connect to it with the client API.